# Playing a recorded welcome message when answering an incoming call (Android)

Tags: android, phone, voice-recording, voice

I would like to know if it is possible to have a pre-recorded message that plays when I answer a call. For example, I would record something like: "Hello, welcome to ABC limited, this is Alex, how can I help you?"

My phone currently uses Android version 9 and I was wondering if there is an existing application that has this feature or is there any way I can hack into the phone with codes to achieve this.